# How to Disable Alt-Q Closing Application Within Switcher?

Tags: gnome, application-switcher

Too often, my left pinky finger slides off the Tab key and onto the Q key while I'm Alt-Tab'ing through my open windows, resulting in accidentally closing applications.

How can I disable this (or bind it to something harder to mistype)? /org/gnome/desktop/wm/ doesn't seem to have any binding or preference for this in dconf-editor.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Desktop, I believe).

Comment: If you are open to a mechanical solution, take a hot glue gun and draw a ridge of glue on the right side of TAB to make it physically more difficult for your finger to drift onto Q.

Comment: FWIW, I did add info to the question as suggested.

Comment: Interestingly, since changing my config to switch windows (via Alt-Tab) rather than applications, I can't reproduce the Alt-Q behavior -- it seems to have no effect.